# How to filter objects based on type-imposed predicate collections?

Tags: c#, expression-trees, predicate

I have a situation in which i would like to filter objects based on collections of predicates imposed on their particular types:
Could this be done via precompiled  `ExpressionTrees` ?

```
class A
{
   public int Value {get;set;}
}
class B
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public bool IsMajor{get;set;}
}


Dictionary<Type,IEnumerable<Predicate<[object casted to type]>> typePredicateMap=new Dictionary<Type,Predicate<[object casted to type]>>{
   {typeof(A),new List<Predicate<[object casted to A]> { x=>x.Value >100,x=>x.Value<200 }},
   {typeof(B),new List<Predicate<[object casted to B]> { x=>x.Name!="johhnny",x=>x.IsMajor==true }}
}
```

I said above `object casted to Type` since i want my predicate to be based on that particular type..

```
public static bool MeetsCriteria(object data)
{
    Type type=typeof(data);
    IEnumerable<Predicate<object>predicates=typePredicateMap[type];
    bool isValid=true;
    foreach(var predicate in predicates)
    {
        isValid&=predicate(data);  //
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that since we want to dynamically choose the predicates to call, they need to be of type `Predicate<object>`, since the type we are invoking them on is `object`. Due to the fact that `Predicate<T>` is *contravariant* (defined as `Predicate<in T>`), that means that we can specify a less-derived type for T where a more derived type is expected.

In practice that means that if you had a class `A` and class `B : A`, you could use a `Predicate<A>` as a `Predicate<B>` or a `Predicate<object>` as `Predicate<A>`, but you can't do `Predicate<A>` where `Predicate<object>` is expected. This means that your predicates will have to be of type `Predicate<object>` and cast the object parameter to the right type manually.

I guess that was a long-winded way of saying you just have to use `Predicate<object>` everywhere, or find some way to constrain your input objects. Does your `MeetsCriteria` method *really* need to handle every object which might ever exist?

I don't believe what your are asking for is possible to solve with expression trees since the problem with types will still be present, but hey, maybe someone will prove me wrong.

Comment: I could restrict it to a lets say class hierarchy , but the problem is the same.I have some type of objects (maybe derived from a common parent) but i need to be able to provide predicates based on the derived types.

Comment: The core problem is still that you are trying to invoke a typed function on something which, as far as the C# compiler knows, is of type `object`. How would it know what type to cast it to before calling the function? You could try to work around this by for example making a generic class like `PredicateContainer<T>` which can have a method taking an `object` argument, checking if it is of type T, and if so then calling the specified typed delegate. My point is that you can't accomplish this in a strongly-typed way.

Comment: But i am not looking to accomplish it in a strongly typed it way.I just would likeil to do it in an efficient way since the objects will be arriving from a message queue with high throughput